# Android Coroutine function callback

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlinx.coroutines

Here is my fun in the **Repository** that returns me the String Id from the Group name

```
@Suppress(“RedundantSuspendModifier”)
@WorkerThread
suspend fun fetchGroupId(groupName: String): String {
      return groupDao.fetchGroupId(groupName)
}
```

And this is the function on the **ViewModel**

```
fun getGroupId(groupName: String) = scope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
      groupId = repository.fetchGroupId(groupName)
}
```

Now I want this group Id on the Activity side what I need to do?

Comment: what about using **higer order function** as callback?

Comment: I'm new with **Coroutine**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use callback by using **Higher order function** as callback parameter to provide data back to calling method like below :

```
fun getGroupId(groupName: String, callback: (Int?) -> Unit) = scope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
    callback(repository.fetchGroupId(groupName))
}
```

This method would be used like below in your `Activity`:

```
mViewModel.getGroupId("your group name here") { id ->
    // Here will be callback as group id
}
```

Comment: What about the observe when It's use for list only or I can use that in this fun also

Comment: You can pass multiple parameters as arguments to function declaration. `callback: (Int?, List? ... any number of parameters you need.) -> Unit`

Comment: Okay this is really help full. Can You give me the best tutorial site to learn the Coroutine

Comment: You can follow official doc, i found it helpful.

Comment: I got this error Can you me what is the issue? `FATAL EXCEPTION: DefaultDispatcher-worker-3`

Comment: This might be helpful -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45326818/cant-catch-exception-throwing-after-kotlin-coroutine-is-cancelled

Comment: I got group id null.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an interface something like :-

```
interface GroupIdViewContract{ fun returnId(groupId : String) }
```

in ViewModel

```
fun getGroupId(groupName: String) = scope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
groupId = repository.fetchGroupId(groupName)
viewContract?.returnId(groupId)
}
```

then you can implement this interface in your activity and you can easily get this group id in your activity

Comment: thanks for your help your method is also correct but I was not using the interface so I use another way. Thank You

Comment: You can follow MVP framework if you are using Kotlin and Coroutine. You will not face such problems

Comment: What about the MVVM?

Comment: No doubt, it is more automated than MVP, but while working with Kotlin and coroutine, it helped me a lot in understanding coroutine and kotlin, so I usually recommend MVP to those who have just started using kotlin or coroutine.

Comment: Thanks You for the help

Answer (score 1):

That's what you need [Callbacks and Kotlin Flows](https://medium.com/@elizarov/callbacks-and-kotlin-flows-2b53aa2525cf).
For example Single-shot callback:

```
interface Operation<T> {
    fun performAsync(callback: (T?, Throwable?) -> Unit)
}


suspend fun <T> Operation<T>.perform(): T =
suspendCoroutine { continuation ->
    performAsync { value, exception ->
        when {
            exception != null -> // operation had failed
                continuation.resumeWithException(exception)
            else -> // succeeded, there is a value
                continuation.resume(value as T)
        }
    }
}
```